# Foreign Key Error(length issues)

Tags: sql-server

Here is my code.

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORY 
(
    CategoryNo int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AutoIncCategoryNo AS 'CAT' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(CategoryNo AS VARCHAR(5)),5) PERSISTED,
    CategoryName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AutoIncCategoryNo)
);

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT 
(
    ProductNo int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AutoIncProduct AS 'P' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ProductNo AS VARCHAR(5)),5) PERSISTED,
    ProductName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CategoryCode VARCHAR(5),
    UnitPrice decimal(6,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (AutoIncProduct),
    CONSTRAINT CategoryCode_Constraint
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryCode)
    REFERENCES CATEGORY(AutoIncCategoryNo) 
);
```

I have 2 tables as shown above. And here is the error that I got.

> Column 'CATEGORY.AutoIncCategoryNo' is not the same length or scale as
>   referencing column 'PRODUCT.CategoryCode' in foreign key
>   'CategoryCode_Constraint'. Columns participating in a foreign key
>   relationship must be defined with the same length and scale.

How can I fix it?

Comment: This might help you [How to put foreign key constraints on a computed fields in sql server?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2548873/3752496)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create foreign key constraints at that time make sure column data type and size are equal. Try this.

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORY (
    CategoryNo int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AutoIncCategoryNo AS 'CAT' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(CategoryNo AS VARCHAR(5)),5) PERSISTED,
    CategoryName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (AutoIncCategoryNo)
);

    CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
    ProductNo int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AutoIncProduct AS 'P' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ProductNo AS VARCHAR(5)),5) PERSISTED,
    ProductName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CategoryCode VARCHAR(8),
    UnitPrice decimal(6,2),
    PRIMARY KEY (AutoIncProduct),
    CONSTRAINT CategoryCode_Constraint
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryCode)
    REFERENCES CATEGORY(AutoIncCategoryNo) 
);
```

Comment: I am new to sql server, can you explain to me why is it 8? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 'CAT' with Varchar(5) in the CATEGORY.AutoIncCategoryNo column

but PRODUCT.CategoryCode is VARCHAR(5).
you have to MAKE IT AS VARCHAR(8).

Answer (score 0):

Column 'Student.Admission_Number' is not the same length or scale as referencing column 'atten.Admission_Number' in foreign key 'FK__atten__Admission__75A278F5'. Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale